# what's the CDF of Product of 3 complex random Gaussian variables?

Tags: statistics

there are 3 complex Gaussian random variables, A, B,C, A~CN(0,\sigma_1^2),B~CN(0,\sigma_2^2),C~CN(0,\sigma_2^2), any two of them are independent, then how can I derive the CDF of the random variable D=ABC.In fact, I tried to use triple integral but I don't know how to solve it. Any guides would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution can be given in terms of a Meijer-G function according to [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html)

[image]

To get here from the result relating to two distributions which is 
[image]
evaluating to
[image]

You can consider using the convolution of two G functions:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} G_{p,q}^{\,m,n} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} \mathbf{a_p} \\ \mathbf{b_q} \end{matrix} \; \right| \, \eta x \right)
G_{\sigma, \tau}^{\,\mu, \nu} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} \mathbf{c_{\sigma}} \\ \mathbf{d_\tau} \end{matrix} \; \right| \, \omega x \right) dx = \\
 \frac{1}{\eta} \; G_{q + \sigma ,\, p + \tau}^{\,n + \mu ,\, m + \nu} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} - b_1, \dots, - b_m, \mathbf{c_{\sigma}}, - b_{m+1}, \dots, - b_q \\ - a_1, \dots, -a_n, \mathbf{d_\tau} , - a_{n+1}, \dots, - a_p \end{matrix} \; \right| \, \frac{\omega}{\eta} \right) = \\\frac{1}{\omega} \; G_{p + \tau ,\, q + \sigma}^{\,m + \nu ,\, n + \mu} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} a_1, \dots, a_n, -\mathbf{d_\tau} , a_{n+1}, \dots, a_p \\ b_1, \dots, b_m, -\mathbf{c_{\sigma}}, b_{m+1}, \dots, b_q \end{matrix} \; \right| \, \frac{\eta}{\omega} \right)
$$

and consider the representation of the Bessel $K$ function and the third Gaussian in terms of the Meijer-G function. For example:
$$
K_\nu (x) = \frac{1}{2} \; G_{0,2}^{\,2,0} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} - \\ \frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{-\nu}{2} \end{matrix} \; \right| \, \frac{x^2}{4} \right), \qquad \frac{-\pi}{2} < \arg x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

From here it may be possible to get a form for the CDF, but it may not be expressible in simpler functions. There are relations for derivatives of the Meijer-G function given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/20/ShowAll.html)

Comment: Does it still holds for complex case？I don’t know the essence behind the Meijer-G function. Does it just offer a notation for a function and machanism to calculate？Thanks！

Comment: @PalaceW Essentially yes, it is a way of encoding a generalised series expansion. For complex values this may be defined though analytic continuation but that quickly gets complicated. The calculation using G functions appears to be the mechanism behind many computer algebra systems and the methods they use to solve general symbolic integration problems.